# Same string representation results in different outcome

Tags: java, facebook

I am currently facing an issue which is driving me nuts:

The following code snippet is the wrapping part to send a request to Facebook to create a new post. This works fine for directly posted and not-scheduled posts currently. I've added the `char[]` and `chars` for debugging purposes.

```
public GenericResponse createNewPost(final String accessToken, final String target, final String message)
{
    char[] messageRawBytes = message.toCharArray();
    int char1 = (int) messageRawBytes[0];
    int char2 = (int) messageRawBytes[1];
    final String URL = SystemParameters.FB_API_BASE_URL + target + "/feed?access_token=" + accessToken;
    final Map<String, String> params = new TreeMap<>();
    params.put("message", message);
    return new PostRequest(URL, params).send();
}
```

Everytime (either from the database or from the REST API directly) it enters the function, the Emoji  is represented by the char values of `55357` and `56613` (which is correct for `UTF-16`) each time and the String `message` looks the same in the debugger and there is no other difference after. However, Facebook is only displaying a `?` when the post was read from the database and displays the proper Emoji only, when posted directly via the REST API.

What am I overseeing here? This obviously seems to be some sort of charset problem, but since the String `message` has the same value everytime, it can't be anything of the further processing, can it?

Comment: I feel your database and column should support UTF-16 encoding. This has to be at Database Level, Table Level and Column Level. What Database you are using ?

Comment: Note that the name of `char[] messageRawBytes` is misleading: it's not the raw bytes at all (you'd get those by calling `getBytes(encoding)`).

Comment: For debugging purposes would it be possible to load the string from the db as well as post it via the REST api and call `equals()` on them just to be sure they _really_ are the same?

Comment: The database is a mariadb set to `utf8mb4` - Hibernate and mariadb are configured to work with `utf8mb4`. I've just read the value from the database and compared it with `equals` - outputs true in each case (message from REST API and from database) ... this makes no sense.

Comment: Well, this makes no sense at all, but did overcome this issue when changing the underlying `javax.ws.rs.client` to a  `org.apache.http.impl.client` - the first one is from the EE standard. I still have no clue why - I can only guess that this was caused by something like a hidden charset or context charset.